# Как назвать блок?

Tags: веб-программирование

У меня имеется header и в нем находится 2 блока, навигация (она внизу) и на верхнем плане у меня находится блок, в котором лежат номера, кнопка поддержки и иконки соц сетей. Так вот, как назвать этот блок с номерами?

Comment: Контакты, что ли?

Comment: Ну что-то типа такого

Answer (score 0):

Не принципиально. Хоть `block_numbers` Если следовать логике компонентов, то необходимо называть, от того, что там происходит. Но можно и углубиться в эту теорию, и следовать к примеру [БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) методологии.

Comment: да, но как его назвать по бэму?

Comment: Я же дал ссылку на документацию. Есть видео уроки. Это совершенно не важно, в каждой команде их называют по своему. Есть Атомарное название классов, есть `CSS in JS`

Answer (score 0):

Если по БЭМ-у то просто numbers или our-contacts(последнее слово в таком названии может описывать роль этого элемента,например если это список чисел то number-list), так как это отдельный, независимый блок. Для размещения(позиционирования) этого блока в другом блоке можно добавить еще один класс, например:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="numbers numbers_black header__nambers">
    ...
    </div>
</header>
```

Так можно понять, что это блок "numbers"является дочерним элементом блока "header".
Для модификации блока добавляется еще один класс "numbers_black".

https://ru.bem.info/methodology/

Если ваш проект будут поддерживать другие люди(в дальнейшем), то есть смысл называть элементы, так что бы было понятно, какую роль элемент выполняет в разметке и это принципиально!